# React useQuery infinite request to server when dockerized

Tags: reactjs, docker, apollo, apollo-client

I have a React app using apollo-client. My initial query is whether the user is logged in or not and it shows a loading page until server responses so it knows to go to dashboard page or login page. Everything works fine in development, even when I build the project without dockerizing it works just fine but when I use docker, it shows this weird behavior of requesting the initial query over and over. Server responses just fine but useQuery sends another request in an infinite loop.

**Specs:**

- react: `v17.0.2`
- apollo-client: `v3.5.7`
- node image: `v14.19.1`
- server: `django 3.2`

network stats when not using docker:
[image]

network stats when using docker:
[image]

Requests just go on infinitely.

useQuery code:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(
gql`
  query {
    # query string
  }
`,
{
  skip:
    !performAuthentication ||
    (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" &&
      process.env.REACT_APP_REMOTE_SERVER === "false"),
}
```

);

the query skips if redux has a user or the env is in development mode while not requesting to server.

Dockerfile code:

```
FROM node:14.19.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install -g express
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build
```

jsx uses loading value to show a loading string or its children. since loading is always true it gets stuck in loading string.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**
context component code:

```
const AuthContext = createContext(null);

function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const authenticationStore = useSelector((state) => 
  state.authentication);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  let performAuthentication = !authenticationStore.isInitialized;

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(
    gql`
      query {
        # query string
      }
    `,
    {
      skip:
    !performAuthentication ||
    (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" &&
      process.env.REACT_APP_REMOTE_SERVER === "false"),
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading === false) {
      if (data) {
        dispatch(
          setUser({
            isInitialized: true,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            user: data.myProfile,
          })
        );
      } else if (error) {
        dispatch(resetUser());
      }
    }
  }, [loading]);

  if (
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" &&
    process.env.REACT_APP_REMOTE_SERVER === "false" &&
    performAuthentication
  ) {
    dispatch(
      setUser({
        isInitialized: true,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: {
          id: 1,
          name: "John Doe",
          firstName: "John",
          lastName: "Doe",
          email: "john@hrm.com",
        },
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Post is edited. If it's not enough, please tell me what part is needed.

Comment: Can you post the complete react component you're using the `useQuery`? You can strip it down to the important parts if you can't show the entire code. This is just to make a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added the context code. there is a hook using this context to set authentication attributes. the weird thing is that it works just fine in development and production without docker. when the docker build it, the problem arises.

Comment: The code looks fine. Looks like it's something to do with Docker. Can you try running your container with `--network="host"` in your `docker run` command to make sure the service is able to connect to `localhost` (Assuming it's connecting to `localhost`)?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and could not figure it out for the life of me.
[image: successful useQuery triggers infinite loop]
function GetProfile(){

```
const { loading, error, data }  = useQuery( GET_USER, { variables : { _id: 'bee82b90' } } )

// .then( () => { console.log( "test" ) } ) ; 
//   , onError: () => console.log( "error" )
//   ,  onCompleted: () => { console.log( data ) ; }
//  }); 

if (loading) return 'Loading...';

if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

return <div>{data}</div>
```

};

I as soon as I add this simple component the query runs successfully but infinite loop kicks off. As soon as I remove the component the loop stops

When I add a mutation in the same place it runs just fine with no loop.

I too am running a Dockerized server ... at least I know I'm not alone.

Comment: Can you try running your container with `--network="host"` in your `docker run` command to make sure the service is able to connect to `localhost` (Assuming it's connecting to `localhost`)?